# Lightning Web Component Bad Request after lots successful calls

Tags: apex, api, lightning-web-components, json

We have a community custom page developed using LWC to save order. Users sign in, arrive at this page and input your order. There is some apex classes being called from Lightning web component for each user action. When save button is clicked an apex class is called to save the order, this class receive an json object. Every day hundreds of orders are saved by this solution but once in a two days something happened and the apex who save the order all of suddenly stop to response and return the following error:

```
body:
message: "apex://CustomerOrderItemPriceBookController: No apex action available for CustomerOrderItemPriceBookController.createOrderItems"
__proto__: Object
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
```

All others apex classes which only read data keep working normally, but not that class, debug logs don't generated either when this error is occurring.

The temporary solution is remove all user session and ask them to sign in again.

**LWC method:**

```
orderItemCreate({ orderJson: orderJson, orderItemsJson: orderItemJson })
.then(result => {
    if(result){
        console.log('createOrderItem Order created!');
    }
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log('createOrderItem - orderItemCreate error: ' + error);
});
```

**Apex Class:**

```
public with sharing class CustomerOrderItemPriceBookController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static List<OrderItem> createOrderItems(String orderJson, String orderItemsJson){
        Order order = (Order) JSON.deserialize(orderJson, Order.class);
        String error = ''; 
        try {
            insert order;
            List<OrderItem> orderItemList = setOrderItemList(order, orderItemsJson);        
            insert orderItemList;
            return orderItemList;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug('CustomerOrderItemPriceBookController - createOrderItems: ' + ex.getMessage() );
            delete order;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you previewing the LWC component on a local server? Try deploying it and check. It worked for me giving me the impression that it could be unavailability of the object definition.